# 4.0 substitute for `SpaceUVEditor.pixel_snap_mode`?

Tags: add-on

I got a plugin that does not work on 3.6 or 4.0, I'm getting the error:

```
OBJ import of 'vox.obj' took 7.9 ms
Info: Removed 5301 vertice(s)
True
Info: Applied modifier: MrCleaner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\VoxCleaner_V2_Free.py", line 713, in execute
    VoxMethods.UVScaling(context)
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\VoxCleaner_V2_Free.py", line 450, in UVScaling
    space.uv_editor.pixel_snap_mode = 'CORNER'
AttributeError: 'SpaceUVEditor' object has no attribute 'pixel_snap_mode'
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\VoxCleaner_V2_Free.py", line 713, in execute
    VoxMethods.UVScaling(context)
  File "C:\Users\acgc9\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\VoxCleaner_V2_Free.py", line 450, in UVScaling
    space.uv_editor.pixel_snap_mode = 'CORNER'
AttributeError: 'SpaceUVEditor' object has no attribute 'pixel_snap_mode'
```

I know nothing about blender addons creation and the plugin has not recieved any update since last year... It seems that API has changed. What is the new alternative?

Comment: Is this a free addon? Can you share it here?

Comment: I think this is 'pixel_round_mode' now.

Comment: @lemon you are right `space.uv_editor.pixel_round_mode = 'CORNER'` and it works fine! Maybe you can turn your comment into an answer and I select it.

Comment: @Psyonic [this](https://github.com/TheStrokeForge/Vox-Cleaner-V2) is the plugin... I opened an issue anyway